# Searching for stuff in GitHub repo through mobile web

Tags: github, github-issues

Is there a way to search project issues while using GitHub from a mobile browser? I could not find a search box for searching through project stuff. I was expecting the same functionality as in the desktop website.

[image: screen shot from Github in mobile browser]

Answer (score 1):

Hitting the "burger menu" on the left will open a navigation that will also include a "Search" field:

[image]

If you go to the start page, the search field will apply to the whole github.com. On organizations, the organization's repositories only, and inside a repository on the content of that repository.

If scroll all the way down, you will also have a link "Desktop version" that you can use to switch to the full, desktop version of GitHub.